# Add the UUID from blkid into the /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, shell, awk, command, mount

Need to add the UUID of the disk into the /etc/fstab file.

Input

```
cat /blkid | awk '{print $2}' | <TODO:>

UUID=e3vm2eea-9oe6-4k01-420f-554fd5frc0 
UUID=e4vm2eea-9oe6-4j01-420f-143fx5fkc0 
UUID=e5vm2eea-9oe6-4i01-420f-154fd5lhc0
```

Expected Output :

```
<file system> <mount point>   <type default value>  <options default value>       <dump default value>  <pass default value>
UUID=e3vm2eea-9oe6-4k01-420f-554fd5frc0 /part/1 ext4  acl,rw,noatime 0 2
UUID=e4vm2eea-9oe6-4j01-420f-143fx5fkc0 /part/2 ext4 acl,rw,noatime 0 2
UUID=e5vm2eea-9oe6-4i01-420f-154fd5lhc0 /part/3 ext4 acl,rw,noatime 0 2
```

Along with UUID need to add the mount partitions, type, option, dump, pass and Mount Partitions is dynamic (1,2,3) All should expect in shell command.

Answer (score 1):

like this ?

```
# blkid | awk '{print $2" /part/"NR" ext4 acl,rw,noatime 0 2"}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `awk` which will break if the columns ever change, it would be better to utilise `blkid -s UUID`

Examples:

```
# blkid -s UUID /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="a7d4c7ff-2ccc-4171-8976-aca87c5a24bd"
# blkid -s UUID -o value /dev/sdb1
a7d4c7ff-2ccc-4171-8976-aca87c5a24bd
```